# Correct use of arguments in camel exec

Tags: apache-camel

I can't figure out the syntax for doing the following:

```
bteq < /data/bteqs/test.bteq
```

Using camel-exec http://camel.apache.org/exec.html with blueprint XML.

I'm probably missing something pretty trivial here - so far I've tried to pass the whole "< /data/bteqs/test.bteq" part as an argument.

I've also tried to overcome the issue by using eval:

```
<to uri="exec:eval?args=&quot;bteq &lt; /data/bteqs/test.bteq&quot;"/>
```

But apparently eval doesn't work with exec at least on my OS:

```
2018-05-23 12:50:15,017 | INFO  | .xml-43_Worker-2 | bteq-test-route                  
| 43 - org.apache.camel.camel-core - 2.16.5 | ERROR :: Unable to execute 
command ExecCommand [args=[bteq < /data/bteqs/test.bteq], executable=eval, 
timeout=9223372036854775807, outFile=null, workingDir=null, 
useStderrOnEmptyStdout=false]
STACKTRACE :: org.apache.camel.component.exec.ExecException: Unable to 
execute command ExecCommand [args=[bteq < /data/bteqs/test.bteq], 
executable=eval, timeout=9223372036854775807, outFile=null, workingDir=null, 
useStderrOnEmptyStdout=false]
```

Answer (score 0):

Just a guess, but perhaps you have to use the shell as "runtime" to execute the command.

```
<to uri="exec:sh?args=&quot;bteq &lt; /data/bteqs/test.bteq&quot;"/>
```